# Why is brunch adding in this requirejs code?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, brunch

I have a file `app/js/d3.js` in a brunch project that uses requirejs. When I build the file, the code in `app/js/d3.js` is concatenated into `app.js` as expected. But it is wrapped in what looks like some require code, as follows:

```
require.register("js/d3", function(exports, require, module) { #this wrapper is added
window.onload = function() { #then there is the start of code from app/js/d3.js
```

I am new enough to require that I can't tell if this is supposed to happen or if this is unintended behavior from Brunch. When I search the [require api](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) for register I don't see a register method.

What's going on? Why is my code getting wrapped this way? My config.coffee looks like this:

```
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        "js/app.js": /^app/
        "js/vendor.js": /^(bower_components|vendor)/
      order:
        before: [
          'bower_components/queue-async/queue.js',
          'bower_components/topojson/topojson.js',
          'bower_components/topojson/topojson.js',
          'bower_components/d3/d3.js',
          'bower_components/requirejs/requirejs.js'
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to add this code to my config file

```
  files:
    ...
  modules:  //this stops the wrapping
    wrapper: false
```